# MySql calculation returning zero when no record

Tags: mysql

Good morning, banging my head against a wall with this & was hoping to get some advice. I have  3 tables joined to display sales data as below;

```
Select
  a._CommMonth As Month,
  Sum(a._CommDue) As Commission,
  Sum(a.`Network Paid`) As Company,
  Sum(a.Payable) As Adviser,
  c.Fee As Charge,
  Sum(a.Payable) - (c.Fee) As Total
From
  pms_payments.dbo_payments a 
  Inner Join pms_payments.dbo_nscontacts b 
  On b._Firm_Name = a._Firm_Name 
  Left Join pms_payments.dbo_clawback c 
  On b.ContactID = c.ContactID And a._CommMonth = c.Month
Where
  b.ContactID = 199
Group By
  a._CommMonth
```

The Sum(a.Payable) - (c.Fee) As Total field is where I am having issues, if no record exists in c.fee table then nothing is returned such as 100 - [No record] = 100. If a record is present the value is deducted as expected such as 100 - 15 = 85.

Does that make sense?

Thanks

Comment: Arr you expecting to get 100 or 0 or null?

Comment: Which of the grouped records do you want?  You're not applying an aggregate function to `c.Fee`.

Comment: when creating the table r u sure that u havent set any default value , cuz ur row might be set to recieve 0 in place of null by default , u can check that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

> IFNULL(expr1,expr2)
>
> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the
>   context in which it is used.

Something like

```
Sum(a.Payable) - IFNULL(c.Fee,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, instead of getting 100 - no record = 100, you are getting 100 - no record = [nothing].

Presuming this is correct, then I believe your problem stems from the fact that null is not the same as zero (and is not a valid number). You can use the IFNULL() function to replace a null value with zero and your subtraction should work.

Please let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there & thanks to you both, the IFNULL function was exactly what I needed. Sorry I could not accept both answers, really appreciate the effort & time though.

```
Sum(a.Payable) - IFNULL (c.Fee,0) As Total
```

Regards

Gary